# How to get file name as a command line argument in Java

Tags: java, file

I am making a simple program to read a file to get data from it for a project.I have hard coded the file name and directory in my Java code. But now I want to pass my file name as a command line argument in my program.Is there an easy way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Oracle's documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, there should be a parameter that is an array of strings. This paremeter holds the tokenized command line arguments passed when your program is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app from command lines, then you can use `argv[0]` for full path or `"%1"` for file name only in your properties inspector.